# Interview Q: Store 1KB of information on a PC that will have storage replaced

Tags: storage

I interviewed for a job and got asked a very interesting interview question. I'm still thinking about it.

The question:

> “How can you store 1KB of information on a standard Windows desktop computer, that will have its storage (HDD or SSD) completely replaced?”

I wasn’t able to come up with an answer.

Comment: Easy, just print it out and stick to the case. Seriously though, while it's an interesting challenge, I don't know what it's supposed to achieve as an interview question.

Comment: Maybe overwrote the boot sector? Who knows. This seems like a ridiculous interview question. It only achieves confusion.

Comment: That's pretty standard for interview questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Standard Windows computers nowadays run EFI firmware, which has a separate NVRAM storage as part of the motherboard, used to store "EFI variables". Its capacity varies from device to device, but 1KB will easily fit on any system. The [SetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableEx()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfirmwareenvironmentvariableexw) function can be used to set custom EFI variables from within Windows apps.

Many Windows computers also contain a TPM, which has its own non-volatile storage available to the OS. The capacity is also small, but 1KB should still fit in a single "NV index". To access the NVRAM in TPM 2.0 systems, you would use a TSS library (such as Microsoft's own [TSS.MSR](https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR)) which provides the NvDefineSpace() and NvWrite() functions.

(TPM 1.2 devices also have the same feature but use a completely different command set. I'm not sure whether anyone has written a TPM 1.2 TSS for Windows; it might be necessary to do everything manually through [Tbsip_Submit_Command()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tbs/nf-tbs-tbsip_submit_command).)